# How can I get the 10 most recent rows from a database?

Tags: sql, datetime, subquery, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I want to choose an `id` in a table, sort it by date and show only the
10 newest entries.

I have already tried following command:

```
SELECT * FROM weather 
  WHERE DATUM = (SELECT MAX(DATUM) WHERE ID='0')
```

Comment: Hello Melvin, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you explain exactly what you want ? You talk about a table but you SQL command has 2 tables ! Can you give an example with data on 2 tables and what you are expecting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want filtering, sorting and limiting:

```
select *
from weather
where id = 0          -- filter on the given "id"
order by datum desc   -- sort by most recent date
limit 10              -- keep the 10 most recent only
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM weather
WHERE DATUM = (SELECT MAX(DATUM)
               FROM orders
               WHERE ID='0')
order by DATUM DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could helps anyone.

This matter associated to any range of date and time specifically. So you can easy to customize for your application.

```
/* mySQL doesn't permit to use limit clause on sub query at where clause statement.
   Therefore we are using join clause as an alternative.
*/

select w.*
from weather w
inner join (
    select min(DATUM) fromDate, max(DATUM) toDate
    from (
        select DATUM from ORDERS where ID = '0'
        order by DATUM desc limit 10
    ) t
) o
on w.DATUM between o.fromDate and o.toDate
order by w.DATUM desc

/* Transaction table with limited rows option */

select w.*
from weather w
inner join (
    select min(DATUM) fromDate, max(DATUM) toDate
    from orders where ID = '0'
) o
on w.DATUM between o.fromDate and o.toDate
order by w.DATUM desc limit 10
```